# EDI Catalog file Creation

Tags: edi

My boss just give me a CSV file and he want to make a EDI catalog 832 file by the CSV file .I am searching a lot to figure it out , If anybody know that , Please share the experience step by step. It will be highly appreciated .

I want to make EDI 832 catalog file from a CSV file .

Comment: Your "boss" needs to provide the mapping of what data elements in the CSV match the 832 standard elements you are expected to use.  Without any EDI experience, this is a silly request.

Answer (score 0):

So, generally, the partner that requests the 832 will have specifications for what they expect in those fields. You will also have to know the business content of your CSV file in order to properly map the fields from the CSV to 832 format. There are online tools that can help with the conversion (see Babelway for example). Their usage kind of depends on if this is a one time thing, or the kind of conversion you're going to require regularly. Parsing a CSV is pretty straightforward but building a valid X12 message can be quite tricky, especially if you hope for it to be properly received by various partners which don't necessarily support the same versions and specs.

Comment: is there any specific tools where I can directly covert the CSV file to 832 Catalog file

Comment: Sorry, no free tool